# Is reselect needed when I just map the normal state to a component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I'm new to reselect and I understand the need. I think it's awesome. However, in my case it kind-of seems like it adds a lot of extra code for no reason. Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

**Previous Component:**

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        day: state.filters.day,
        minDate: state.filters.minDate,
        maxDate: state.filters.maxDate,
    };
};
```

**Now Selectors:**

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getDay = state => state.filters.day;
export const makeGetDay = () => createSelector(
    getDay,
    day => day,
);

const getMinDate = state => state.filters.minDate;
export const makeGetMinDate = () => createSelector(
    getMinDate,
    date => date,
);

const getMaxDate = state => state.filters.maxDate;
export const makeGetMaxDate = () => createSelector(
    getMaxDate,
    date => date,
);
```

**Now Component:**

```js
const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
    const getDay = makeGetDay();
    const getMinDate = makeGetMinDate();
    const getMaxDate = makeGetMaxDate();
    return state => ({
        day: getDay(state),
        minDate: getMinDate(state),
        maxDate: getMaxDate(state),
    });
};
```

**To clarify**, the code works, I just don't understand what Reselect adds in this case..

Comment: AFAIK, reselect also memoizes the resulting value.  So, if you use the selector in many places, you won't be calling the function every time.

Comment: But, then again, how is that different from just selecting yourself? I get it when it's the case of filtering an array, but when it isn't?

Comment: And, one could say that it decouples from the store, but how does it do that, since it still depends that there is a store that has an object called filters and inside it day, minDate and maxDate?

Comment: I think for your use case, there isn't much value, just a different way to reference.  Why are you trying to use `reselect` anyway?

Comment: I'm not, I just don't want to miss out on technologies, so I test all the technologies I find to see if they could be useful in any way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the cases you have specified in your question `Reselect` does not actually add any value.

The reason is that `connect` provided by `react-redux` will do it's own shallow compare of the props provided in your `mapStateToProps` function to determine if a render is required. In the examples you provided if the values of `day`, `minDate` or `maxDate` do not change you will not be wasting any time with unnecessary renders.

The real value of `Reselect` comes in when your selector returns something that is computed.

To borrow an example from Vlad.
`Reselect` is great for composing selectors so your selectors may look like this:

```
export const getDay = state => state.filters.day;
export const getMinDate = state => state.filters.minDate;
export const getMaxDate = state => state.filters.maxDate;

export const getIsDateOutOfRange = createSelector(
  getDay,
  getMinDate,
  getMaxDate,
  (day, minDate, maxDate) => day > maxDate || day < minDate
);
```

And your `mapStateToProps` function may look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isOutOfRange: getIsDateOutOfRange(state)
});
```

In this case `Reselect` is providing a nice syntax for combining selectors and a marginal performance benefit from the fact that `getIsDateOutOfRange` will only be re-computed if one of it's dependant selectors returns a different value.

And there in lies the hidden performance benefit of `Reselect`.
If you have a selector that returns a computed array or an object then two identical values returned from the selector will not pass a shallow equality check that `Reselect` or `connect` will use for memoization purposes.

```
[0, 1] === [0, 1] // false
```

So for a contrived example:

```
export const getDays = state => state.filters.days;
export const getMinDate = state => state.filters.minDate;
export const getMaxDate = state => state.filters.maxDate;

export const getDaysWithinRangeNotPerformant = state => {
    const days = getDays(state);
    const minDate = getMinDate(state);
    const maxDate = getMaxDate(state);
    return days.filter(day => day > minDate && day < maxDate);
};

export const getDaysWithinRangePerformant = createSelector(
    getDay,
    getMinDate,
    getMaxDate,
    (days, minDate, maxDate) =>
        days.filter(day => day > minDate && day < maxDate)
);
```

The performance benefit that `Reselect` unlocks here is two-fold.

First even with multiple calls to `getDaysWithinRangePerformant` the possibly expensive `filter` is only performed if the actual parameters have changed.

Secondly, and most importantly, every time `getDaysWithinRangeNotPerformant` is called by `connect` it will return a new array which means that the shallow compare of the prop in `connect` will be false and `render` will be called again even if the actual days themselves have not changed. Because `getDaysWithinRangePerformant` is memoized by `createSelector` it will return the exact same array instance if the values have not changed and therefore the shallow compare of props in `connect` will be true and it will be able to perform it's own optimisations and avoid an unnecessary render.

And that in my opinion is the big benefit that `Reselect` provides.

Answer (score 2):

First of all - you don't have to use higher order function everywhere to use `reselect`. It's pretty much looks like you are doing unnecessary steps.

**getting rid of Higher Order Functions:**

Code below warks the same way, but looks much more readable(compact)

```js
export const getDay = createSelector(
    state => state.filters.day,
    day => day,
);

export const getMinDate = createSelector(
    state => state.filters.minDate,
    date => date,
);

export const getMaxDate = createSelector(
    state => state.filters.maxDate,
    date => date,
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  day: getDay(state),
  minDate: getMinDate(state),
  maxDate: getMaxDate(state),
});
```

You can go even further. Looks like you are renaming variables couple of times times while they are going to component.

`store.maxDate -> date -> maxDate`

You can make your "selectors" responsible not only for retrieving data from store but also for following naming convention.

```js
export const getDay = createSelector(
  state => state.filters.day,
  day => ({ day }),
);

export const getMinDate = createSelector(
  state => state.filters.minDate,
  minDate => ({ minDate }),
);

export const getMaxDate = createSelector(
  state => state.filters.maxDate,
  maxDate => ({ maxDate }),
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...getDay(state),
  ...getMinDate(state),
  ...getMaxDate(state),
});
```

Maybe benefits of `composition` of selectors become clearlier if you would like to create one more selector based on previous:

Assuming you  have  a component that shows an error when `day` is out of range defined by `maxDate` and `minDate`

```js
export const isDateOutOfRange = createSelector(
  getDay,
  getMinDate,
  getMaxDate,
  ({ day }, { minDate }, { maxDate }) => day > maxDate || day < minDate,
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  showError: isDateOutOfRange(state),
});
```

Comment: Ok, I agree with how to make this code more readable, but why? What is the benefit, in this case, of using reselect. I mean, this is more readable, but it's even more readable by just simply mapping the state to props...

Comment: Only benefit of using reselect in current example, as far i can see, is memorization and ability to reuse selectors in different components. Another valuable thing is composition.